# Обособление несогласованного определения (сущ. в косв. падеже)

Tags: пунктуация

В магазине продавались гамаки из крепкого розового шпагата.

Почему определение не обособляется?

Следующая серия аудиозаписей, на один сеанс слушания, от Андрея Ромашкина.

Предполагается ли запятая в данном случае?

Comment: Предполагается что? Запятая? Их две - есть пояснительный оттенок.  Или кто ОНА?

Comment: Да, запятая. Выходит, что обособлять несогласованное определение следует если есть пояснительный оттенок? А в первом случее? А можно ли во втором случае не ставить запятых?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Следующая серия аудиозаписей, на один сеанс слушания, от Андрея Ромашкина.* || Здесь уточнение (дополнительная информация). С таким же успехом можно было бы использовать скобки:
*Следующая серия аудиозаписей (на один сеанс слушания) от Андрея Ромашкина.*

Если считаете, что информация не дополнительная, а обычная, то запятые можно не ставить. Но тогда возникает двусмысленность: все аудиозаписи на один сеанс слушания. А с уточнением - именно следующая серия на один сеанс.

*В магазине продавались гамаки из крепкого розового шпагата.* || Предлог "из" не требует постановки знаков препинания. Но можно поставить знак, если хотите сделать уточнение, - тогда и пауза будет при чтении. Лучше поставить тире:
*В магазине продавались гамаки — из крепкого розового шпагата.*